# алгоритм вычитания длинных чисел по большому основанию (BASE = 10^k , k > 1)

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Моя реализация вычитания работает корректно только при `k = 1` тоесть когда `BASE = 10`. Увеличиваю `k` скажем на `5` - съедаются нули в результате, например: `514026 - 214021 = 300005` мой код выдаёт неверный ответ `35`.

```
//  left >= right
Big_int operator - (const Big_int& left, const Big_int& right)
{
    Big_int res;
    int carry = 0, i = 0, l = left.length;
    for (i = 0; i < l; i++)
    {
        res[i] = left.number[i] - right.number[i] + carry;
        if (res[i] < 0)
        {       
            res[i] += BASE;
            carry = -1;
        }
        else 
        {
            carry = 0;
        }       
    }

    while (i > 1 && res.number[i-1] == 0)
    {
        --i;
    }

    res.length = i;
    return res;
}
```

Тоесть в приведенном мною тесте если положить `BASE = 10^5`, в каждом элементе массива `number[i]` будет храниться 5 цифр и отнимая из левого числа правое получится что сначала отнимаем из `14026 - 14021 = 3`, далее из `6 - 1 = 5` и в итоге имеем 35 что не верно.
Что делать чтобы при `k > 1` работало корректно ?

Comment: А вы уверены, что нули съедаются? Покажите вашу операцию вывода на печать, могу поспорить, что ошибка именно там.

Comment: @VladD абсолютно уверен. нули съедаются еще до вывода - тоесть в теле цикла  в операторе вычитания. Но на всякий случай приведу и этот код : `void Big_int::print() 
{ 
 for (int i = 0; i < (int)length; ++i)
 {
  printf("%d", number[length-i-1]);
 }
}`

Answer (score 2):

Проблема, как и ожидалось, в выводе. Если ваша «цифра» — `k`-значное число, терять ведущие нули нельзя! Правильно так:

```
void Big_int::print()
{
    printf("%d", number[length-1]);
    for (int j = length - 2; j >= 0; j--)
        printf("%0*d", k, number[j]);
}
```

Comment: :D мдауж, а я думал алгоритм неверный - спс

Comment: @arammis: Пожалуйста!